# jQuery - Disable live click event for particular td

Tags: jquery

I got a table and i assign the click event via .live() to each td (id="min") in every row

View:

```
            <td id="min">
                @Html.Action("GetMinAmount", "Stock", new { id = item.FoodID })
            </td>
```

Controller (to display either image or amount)

```
     // Function to return min amount, if null return "-"
    public string GetMinAmount(int id)
    {
        var food = dbEntities.FOODs.Single(f => f.FoodID == id);
        string output = "";
        if (food.MinAmount == null)
        {
            output += "<img id=\"disable\" src=\"../../Content/Add_in_Images/disable.png\" alt=\"disable\" style=\"background-image: none\"/>";
        }
        else
        {
            return food.MinAmount.ToString();
        }
        return output;
    }
```

Script:

```
       $('#min').live('click', function () { $editdialog.dialog('open'); });
```

But inside the td I can have 2 conditions, one is the "enabled" state which showing the Amount where user can click and edit the amount. If the amount is null, an icon will be displayed and user cannot do anything with it.

Currently I cant remove the click handler for the disabled image. So even the td which suppose to be disabled is clickable also...

I got no idea how can i remove the click handler for the "disabled" td only.

Anyone can help??? Thanks.......

Comment: I just reread and you can target the id, but IDs are unique, I suggest you replace them with classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow change my controller to do it in a "dirty" way i would say?

```
 // Function to return min amount, if null return "-"
    public string GetMinAmount(int id)
    {
        var food = dbEntities.FOODs.Single(f => f.FoodID == id);
        string output = "";
        if (food.MinAmount == null)
        {
            output += "<img class=\"disable\" src=\"../../Content/Add_in_Images/disable.png\" alt=\"disable\" style=\"background-image: none\"/>";
        }
        else
        {
            output += "<h4 class=\"edit\">" + food.MinAmount + "</h4>";
        }
        return output;
    }
```

Just putting my amount in a wrapper and I assign the click event to the td with the amount only...

```
   $('.edit').live('click', function () {
```

Any suggestion regarding this ??

Appreciate all the feedback... Thanks....

Answer (score 5):

Add this after the live click event

```
$("img#disable").parents("td").die("click");
```

Comment: hi, i tried, but it dint work, is it because it do not actually "loop" through every table td?

Comment: not sure how your html looks like right now, but first you shouldn't use an id on an element multiple times. It's better to use a class so something like `$("img.disable")`.
Anyway the code I posted grabs all img tags with id disable, goes up the html dom until it reaches a td en kills the click event. So you don't have to loop

Answer (score 2):

you can try something like this:

```
$('td').live('click', function (e){
    if($(this).hasClass('disabled'))
        {
            e.prefentDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    // do your stuff here
});
```

Comment: This wasn't a copy-paste answer, it was just an example. change `$(this).hasClass('disabled')` to whatever piece of code you use to determine if the td should be clicked or not.

Answer (score 0):

Removing an inline onclick event handler using .removeAttr() doesn't achieve the desired effect in Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8. To avoid potential problems, use .prop() instead:

```
$("#MyTd").prop("onclick", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case e.stopImmediatePropagation() did the trick

```
$('.edit').live('click', function (e) {
   e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```