# How can I intercept a jQuery live click event?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm working on WordPress and using a library that loads its Javascript file at the footer, using `<script src>`.
This is the code I need to block:

```
var $ =jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) 
{
    jQuery('.at-delete_image_button').live('click', function(e)
    {
        data = { /* ... */ };
        $.getJSON(ajaxurl, data, function(response) { /* ... */ });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Right after the `<script src>`, I'm printing the following but it doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready( function($) 
{
    $('.at-delete_image_button').live('click', function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
</script>
```

From the [same Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7752114/1287812) I've found the previous code, I also tried the `.die('click');` method without success.

**[update]**

I forgot to add a DOM screenshot.
[image: dom screenshot]

Comment: .live() is pretty greedy.  It should catch anything that's in the DOM, which means it might not yet be in the DOM.  I can't be sure with this limited code snippet.  Are you loading what it's looking for via AJAX after page load?

Comment: @JoeMills, I tried to resume the code but maybe it was too much. What part do you miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't `preventDefault()` from a `.live()` handler because the event has already propagated when it gets to the `.live()` handler.  You would need to have a handler directly on the actual object itself or on a parent (not using `.live()`).

If there is a parent object that is not dynamically created, you can stop propagation at that parent and it then won't get to the `.live()` handler which is on the `document` object.

You could do that like this:

```
jQuery(static parent selector).on('click', '.at-delete_image_button', function(e) {
    // stop propagation up the parent chain so the click event never gets 
    // to the `document` object where .live() would process it
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

`static parent selector` is a selector that matches a static parent of all `'.at-delete_image_button'` objects.

Comment: That did the trick! Almost one hundred kilos of knowledge, uau, thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd come at it from the other direction, and hook into the AJAX action and cancel it.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_their_action', 'my_cancel_their_action', 1);
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_their_action', 'my_cancel_their_action', 1);

function my_cancel_their_action() {
    exit;
}
```

Comment: +1, **very interesting solution**. In fact, much better than intercepting the `live click`, because all jQuery functionality is retained and I just prevent the Ajax, which was my original problem. I won't mark this one as the correct as the Question was focused on jQ. Kudos and gazillion thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You must use `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` to prevent other handlers of same element to execute. Just keep in mind that your own handler must be write **before** the other one.

Answer (score 1):

Die is the best solution. But before you call it, you have to be sure it's called AFTER plugin bind click on it with live.

To achieve that you can use some callback provided by the plugin. You can also add listener when script is downloaded and add little time out before you use die(), but this have drawback in race between you time out and plugin bind click event. With preventImmediateDefault() you running to the same race - will you bind be faster than plugin one?

Answer (score 0):

You can try some tricks by using css put a hidden layer over this button or rename the class if it's not conflict with your css. It think it's a possible way and safe